# Optimizing a simple SQLite query, if possible !

Tags: sql, sqlite, query-optimization

I would like to optimize this query using SQLite 3.

```
SELECT id FROM Table WHERE value = (SELECT max(value) FROM Table WHERE value < myvalue )
   UNION 
SELECT id FROM Table WHERE value = (SELECT min(value) FROM Table WHERE value > myvalue );
```

I want the 2 closest id from a given value. Example: id 20, value 50. The closest id could be 3 with the value 48 (max value inferior) and above id 4 with value 55 (min value superior).

SQLite 3 has not all the features of a real database, if you have something better I can use, well thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
 (SELECT id FROM test WHERE value < myvalue ORDER BY value DESC LIMIT 1) as below,
 (SELECT id FROM test WHERE value > myvalue ORDER BY value ASC  LIMIT 1) as above;
```

Theorically speaking this should be faster becase it use two table scans intead of four.
Anyway i would create a table with a few millon records and test different queries with
the timer on. (.timer ON in sqlite console).

Also make sure to test with and without an index on value. Sometimes, specially
when the index size if bigger than your memory, indexes are useless.

If speed is the real issue consider an alternative light storage, like Kyoto
Cabinet.

Comment: It seems to run a bit faster but I don't have enough row yet to really see the difference. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do it. I don't know if it's faster in sqlite though. You can always try.

```
select id
from table
where value - myvalue > 0
order by abs(value - myvalue) asc
limit 1
union all
select id
from table
where value - myvalue < 0
order by abs(value - myvalue) desc
limit 1
```

Comment: Each individual query works but all together fails:

[ 1st ORDER BY term does not match any column in the result set ]
Exception Name: NS_ERROR_FAILURE

Comment: maybe my query is lacking parenthesis to delimit the two sub queries unioned.

Comment: I think the error is more on the 2 order by. SQLite doesn't seem to like them.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id FROM Table WHERE value > myvalue ORDER BY value LIMIT 1
SELECT id FROM Table WHERE value < myvalue ORDER BY value DESC LIMIT 1
```

this solution has no sub-selects, table scans and no extraneous group or math functions.
but needs two queries

you should index Table.value